# How to extract content of html tags from a string using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Maybe this is very basic, but I am all confused. 
I have a simple html page with many sections (div). I have a string containing html tags in javascript. The code is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1="<html><body><div id='item1'><h2>This is a heading1</h2><p>This is a paragraph1.</p></div><div id='item2'><h2>This is a heading2</h2><p>This is another paragraph.</p></div><div id='lastdiv'>last</div></body></html>";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="title1"></div>
<div id="new1"></div>
<div id="title2"></div>
<div id="new2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract content of the html tags (from the string in javascript) and display that content in my html page in desired sections.

i.e. I want "This is a heading1" displayed in `<div id="title1">` and "This is a paragraph1." to be displayed in `<div id="new1">` and same for the second pair of tags.

I need all of this to work only on the client side. I have tried to use HTML DOM getElementByTagName method and its getting too complicated. I know very little of jquery. And I am confused. I dont understand how to go about it. Can you guide me what to use - javascript or jquery and how to use it? Is there a way to identify the  from the string and iterate through it?

How to extract "This is heading1" (and similar contents enclosed in the html tags) from str1?? I don't know the index of these hence cannot use substr() or substring() function in javascript.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as both a 'getter' and a 'setter' we can just repeat the pattern of:

- target the element on the page we wish to fill
- give it content from
  the string

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQdCz/10/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1="<html><body><div id='item1'><h2>This is a heading1</h2><p>This is a paragraph1.</p></div><div id='item2'><h2>This is a heading2</h2><p>This is another paragraph.</p></div><div id='lastdiv'>last</div></body></html>";
$(function(){
    var $str1 = $(str1);//this turns your string into real html 

    //target something, fill it with something from the string
    $('#title1').text( $str1.find('h2').eq(0).text() );
    $('#new1').text( $str1.find('p').eq(1).text() );
    $('#title2').text( $str1.find('h2').eq(1).text() );
    $('#new2').text( $str1.find('p').eq(1).text() );
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO , You can do this in jquery in two steps :

**Step 1) Parse the string into an XML/HTML document.**

There are at least two ways to do this:

a) As mentioned by Sinetheta

```
 var htmlString = "<html><div></div></html>";
 var $htmlDoc = $( htmlString );
```

b) Using parseXML

```
var htmlString = "<html><div></div></html>";
var htmlDoc = $.parseXML( htmlString );
var $htmlDoc = $( htmlDoc );
```

Please refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

**Step 2) Select text from the XML/HTML document.**

```
var text = $htmlDoc.text( jquery_selector );
```

Please refer http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 1):

Well,

First of all you should clarify how you are getting the source html from your own html. If you are using Ajax you should tick the source as html, even xml.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('{ID of element}').innerHTML

if use jquery
$('selector').html();

```
<div id="test">hilo</div>
<script>
alert($('#test').html());
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface my answer with the knowledge that I don't think I fully understand what you want to do...however I *think* you want to replace *some* (although you make it sound like all) html with some data source.

I've rigged a simple example is jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rS2Wt/9/

This does a simple replace using jquery on a target div.

Hope this helps, good luck.