# How to extract content of html tags from a string using javascript or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a string containing content in some html tags and also some text alone.

It looks like this :

```
var str =  "<p></p><p><i>blabla</i></p><p><i><b>blaaaaaablaaaaa</b></i></p><iframe src="..." height="111" width="333"></iframe><p></p><p><sub>hello blabla</sub></p><p><br></p><iframe src="..." height="444" width="888"></iframe>"
```

I would like to extract somehow in Javascript or AngularJS only some tag (including **content** and **attributes**) then put them into an array.

For example, if I want only `<iframe>` tag, I should have this :

```
var array = ["<iframe src='...' height='111' width='333'></iframe>", "<iframe src='...' height='444' width='888'></iframe>"];
```

If I want `<p>` tag then :

```
var array = ["", "<i>blabla</i>","<i><b>blaaaaaablaaaaa</b></i>","","<sub>hello blabla</sub>","<br>"];
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

**NOTE :** Don't give an answer **using Jquery** please !

Comment: I believe this would fall under HTML parsing. So I would search SO for that. It's kind of a pain in the arse. Otherwise see if someone has good implementation in Regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189338/how-to-extract-content-of-html-tags-from-a-string-using-javascript-or-jquery   Check this out.. here is your answer.

Comment: Does extract mean also remove from string? Do you need strings of iframes or can they be dom elements also? what are you doing with the results?

Comment: @charlietfl I need strings of iframes yes, like this : `"<iframe src='...' width='...' height='....' ></iframe>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an angular element and get the text out of it.

Example:

```
$scope.array =[];
$scope.eles=
angular.element(str).find('iframe');
[].forEach.call($scope.eles, function (ctl) {
    $scope.name.push(angular.element(ctl).text())
});
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5122/

---

**Edit**
To get all the html of the tag you can do:

```
angular.element(str).find('iframe');
    [].forEach.call($scope.eles, function (ctl) {
        $scope.name.push(ctl.outerHTML)
    });
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5123/

Comment: On the right track but `text()` won't provide outerHTML of the iframe elements

Comment: This is answering **50%** of my question. I need also to have the html tag with his attributes : `["<iframe src='.....' height='...' width='...'>...</iframe>", ....., "<iframe src='.....' height='...' width='...'>...</iframe>"] `

Comment: @Emidomh.. instead of `angular.element(ctl).text()` you can also do  `$scope.name.push(ctl.outerHTML)` to get all outer html

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Almost there but your solution is good ! Take a look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atoplix/8cgebbf9/1/) Can you tell me why it gives me an empty array ?

Comment: @Emidomh look at at this http://jsfiddle.net/8cgebbf9/2/ . you need a wrapper coz angular element needs to be one to be created.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I have a similar problem  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721326/replace-html-tag-in-a-string-using-angularjs)  Can you check it ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
var iFrameArr= str.match("<iframe>(.*)<iframe>");
var iFrameContent = iFrameArr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at splitting up the string with regex using a filter such as `'(<iframe>).*(<\/iframe>)'`. This will find the tags of  and  as well as everything in between, putting it into a capture group per iteration found.

Answer (score 0):

Set the html content to the `DOM` and extract the `iframe tag` using `jquery`

Assuming you have a `div` with `id='test'` in your `DOM`

```
var str = "<div> .... </div> <iframe src=".....">..</iframe> 
  text blabla 
  <iframe src="....."> ....blabla2.... </iframe> 
  ....
  <p>.....</p> 
  ......";
$('#test').html(str);

var ar=[]
$('#test iframe').each(function() {
    var x = $(this).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();//wrap the iframe with element p and get the html of the parent
    ar.push(x)//add the html content to array
});

//now ar contains the expected output
```