# Replace html tag attribute in a string using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a string containing html tags :

```
var str =  "<div><p></p><p><i>blabla</i></p><p><i><b>blaaaaaablaaaaa</b></i></p><iframe src='urlAAA' height='400' width='800'></iframe><p></p><p><sub>hello blabla</sub></p><p><br></p><iframe src='urlBBB' height='400' width='800'></iframe></div>";
```

I want to replace each `<iframe>` tag with `<button>` tag in this way:

`"<button type="button">Click Me for iframe n°1 !</button>"` for first iframe

`"<button type="button">Click Me for iframe n°2 !</button>"` for second iframe

etc....

I'm using angularJS. I think the solution is to do something like this :

```
var ele = angular.element(str);
ele.replaceWith(function(index){
        return "<button type='button'>Click Me for iframe n°" + index + " !</button>";
});
```

But I don't know how to specify this for `<iframe>` tags

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

---

**EDIT :**

Here a new example, what I want to do :

In `var str` I have 2 `<iframe>` tags with different `src` attribute value :

the first iframe has `src='urlAAA'`
the second `src='urlBBB'`

I want to get access to the src attribute and replace it with an another url.

```
function editFrameAttributes(str){
      var array =[];
      var eles= angular.element(str).find('iframe');
      [].forEach.call(eles, function (ctl) {
        array.push(ctl.outerHTML)
      });
      Object.keys(array).forEach(function (key) {
        var tempEl = document.createElement('div');
        tempEl.innerHTML = array[key];

        tempEl.childNodes[0].attributes['src'].value = "www.something.com";
        tempEl.childNodes[0].attributes['width'].value = '1234';

        array[key] = tempEl.innerHTML;
      });
      //then I don't know how to replace old iframes by new iframes in 'str' 

      return newStr;
    }
```

The output should look like this :

```
var str =  "<div><p></p><p><i>blabla</i></p><p><i><b>blaaaaaablaaaaa</b></i></p><div><iframe src='www.something.com' height='400' width='1234'></iframe></div><p></p><p><sub>hello blabla</sub></p><p><br></p><div><iframe src='www.something.com' height='400' width='1234'></iframe></div></div>";
```

Comment: Maybe `new DOMParser`? (I'm not familiar with using it though so I haven't given this as an answer.)

Comment: try angular.element('iframe'); but not sure

Comment: @Erez ?? Then how do you specify `str`

Comment: you get the iframe element? and your function doesnt working?

Comment: you can simply do `str.replace` right?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh No not really, thanks for helping me. I edited my post, hope you see my problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, here the solution I found myself :

```
function editFrameAttributes(str,newSrc){
      var eles = angular.element("<div>"+str+"</div>");
      eles.find('[src]').each(function() {
        this.src = newSrc;
      });
      return eles.html();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5298/)

As you are using a string to generate angular element, You can simply replace the `<iframe>` with `<button>` in the string itself.

Example:

```
$scope.str='<iframe>some iframe text<span>span content</span><span>more span content</span></iframe>';

$scope.newStr= $scope.str.replace('<iframe>','<button>').
replace('</iframe>','</button>')
```