# How to extract contents of specific HTML tag following a match?

Tags: bash, html-parsing

I'm wondering how I can extract the contents of a hyperlink in HTML,

For instance:

```
<article id="post36">
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="/blog/2019/4-14-canaries-in-the-coal-mine.html">Canaries in the Coal Mine</a></h3>
                    <p class="author">Posted by <a href="/blog/authors/moderator.html" rel="author">Moderator</a></p>
                    <p><time><span>Sunday, April 14th, 2019</span> &mdash; 8:17AM</time></p>
                </div>
```

Other posts look like this (no external page):

```
<article id="post33">
                <div>
                    <h3><a href="#post33">Landlines Win Again</a></h3>
                    <p class="author">Posted by <a href="/blog/authors/moderator.html" rel="author">Moderator</a></p>
                    <p><time><span>Friday, December 21st, 2018</span> &mdash; 7:14AM</time></p>
```

In an external script, I am passed the ID of a particular post. In this case, post 36 is below. I have a page containing all the post metadata in article tags like below.

I tried using catting the webpage (I have a local copy) and piping it to `sed -n 's|[^<]*<article\([^<]*\)</article>[^<]*|\1\n|gp'`

That sort of works. It only returns all of the article ids, like this:

```
<article id="post6">
<article id="post5">
<article id="post4">
<article id="post3">
<article id="post2">
<article id="post1">
```

My conclusion is that it only works on the current line. And when I try actually using the ID I get nothing: `sed -n 's|[^<]*<article id="post36">\([^<]*\)</article>[^<]*|\1\n|gp'`

My question here is how can I take advantage of the built-in Unix tools (sed, grep, awk, etc.) to extract the hyperlink? In this case, what I need is `/blog/2019/4-14-canaries-in-the-coal-mine.html`

Yes, I have consulted a number of SO posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015587/get-content-between-a-pair-of-html-tags-using-bash) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189338/how-to-extract-content-of-html-tags-from-a-string-using-javascript-or-jquery), most of which discourage this kind of thing (I tried the native solutions but none worked). Two things:

1. The HTML is formatted nicely. There will never be any extra white spaces, carriage returns, or anything else in the code. The blocks will always look like that. This is a very specific application.
2. Unless it is actually *impossible* to do this without some kind of add on or external program, I'd like to stick with basic Unix tools.

Comment: [Obligatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26428).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I already saw this. But as the answer to this question demonstrates, it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can single the interesting line with [sed addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html). In this case, a regexp pattern to match the `<a href`

```
sed -nre '/h3.*href.*(#post[0-9]+|\/blog\/)/ s/.*<a href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' test.html 
/blog/2019/4-14-canaries-in-the-coal-mine.html
#post33
```

To match by article id add this in front of the `sed` command

```
grep -A3 'article id="post36"' test.html | sed -nre '/h3.*href.*(#post[0-9]+|\/blog\/)/ s/.*<a href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Hey, that helps a lot! But now I need to narrow it down by blog ID, that returns all the hyperlinks for every blog. I don't see "article" in your sed anywhere. Furthermore, some blog posts don't have a separate page, and the hyperlink is of format "#ref", and I don't see these showing up, only the ones that have a separate page. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Yeah, if you provide the proper examples.

Comment: OK, updated with the other kind of post. I would basically call this in a shell script with the blog ID #

Comment: You could, I will leave that exercise to you ;-)

Comment: No, I know how to do that, I was just saying that's how I call it

Comment: I think I made a simple syntax error. I know I'm grepping the file then piping to sed, but why does grep still think I need a file? `grep -A3 /folder/path.html 'article id="post36"' | sed -nre '/h3.*href.*\/blog\// s/.*<a href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'`
grep: article id="post36": No such file or directory

Comment: It is not returning anything. My full line in my script is link=`grep -A3 'article id="post$1"' /home/com/interlinked/blog.html | sed -nre '/h3.*href.*(#post[0-9]+|\/blog\/)/ s/.*<a href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'` and when I echo that out it's empty (just a carriage return)

Comment: Try the `grep` only on command line and make sure $1 is correct on your script, should be a number only.

Comment: Works perfectly from the command line, but I'm wondering single and double quoting how to get the $1 working right...?

Comment: Hmm... link=`grep -A3 "article id=\"post$1\"" /home/com/interlinked/blog.html | sed -nre '/h3.*href.*(#post[0-9]+|\/blog\/)/ s/.*<a href="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'` still doesn't work. Now there's no output.

Comment: `grep -A3 'article id="post'"$1"'"'` or `grep -A3 'article id="post'$1'"'` or `patt=$(printf 'article id="post%d"' $1); grep -A3 "$patt" `. BTW, remember the shebang at the beginning of the script `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I've got the shebang, let me try those out

Comment: The last one works the best. Now it is returning a URL for each one. Not necessarily the right URL. It is returning ones that start with # but I can't figure out what's gone wrong... I'll take a closer look and see what the problem is in the morning. Thanks!